# Text is not being wrapped in same line though there is enough space

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

This is my code

```
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
        <Text>This is the title which can upto two lines beyond the card size</Text> : null}
        <Icons name={'dot'} />
        <Text>Kishore3</Text>
   </View>
```

Output looks like this

[image]

If we look at the image we can notice that there is enough space where yellow line is drawn. But `dot` and text `kishore3` went to next line.

How to use the available space as much as possible?

note: It's ok even it renders only two or three characters of `Text`.

Comment: It is probally because `<text>` uses breaks.

try putting the icon and kishore3 inside the first `<text>`.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try this

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
        <Text>This is the title which can upto two lines beyond the card size <Icons name={'dot'} /> <Text>Kishore3</Text></Text> : null}
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide flex into ratio 0.7:0.1:0.2

```
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{ flex: 0.7}}>This is the title which can upto two lines beyond the card size</Text>
        <Icons style={{ flex: 0.1}} name={'dot'} />
        <Text style={{ flex: 0.2}}>Kishore3</Text>
   </View>
```